# Get the capacity of an ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java, queue

I need to shrink an ArrayBlockingQueue capacity by 1.

I was thinking nothing should be easier:

1. Get the capacity of the current queue.
2. Create a new queue with `capacity - 1`
3. Use the `BlockingQueue.drainTo` function to move over any elements in the old queue to the new queue.
4. Take the rest of the day off...

However, I am thoroughly bugged at step 1. For some inconceivable reason ArrayBlockingQueue does not expose the capacity. I can think of no reason for this to be private, it is a *bounded* queue and offers the `getRemainingCapacity` method, why can I not get the capacity?

I cannot do `size() + getRemainingCapacity()` because this is a concurrent queue, there is always the possibility of something changing the queue in between the size and getRemainingCapacity calls.

Surely I am not the first person to need a capacity for an ArrayBlockingQueue. Short of extending the whole class to add a `getCapacity` method, or creating a separate structure to map the capacity of my queues, is there a simple solution for this?

Or maybe an intelligent reason why the capacity should not be known? (aside from an oversight)

**More background:** My multi-threaded program uses many queues, it calls the `BlockingQueue.getRemainingCapacity` function to know when a queue is full and then process it from there. In a rare corner case the program discovers that the queue capacity is 1 element too large partway through filling it up. I need to reduce the size of the queue by 1 otherwise it will never fill up and never get processed.

Comment: Have you tried tracking capacity your self, ArrayBlockingQueue accepts capacity parameter in constructor, it will be ugly solution but it would hopefully work?

Comment: @DusanMalusev Ya I was trying to avoid that, because I have hundreds of these queues... for now I am going with extending the class, it seems really obtuse for this simple usage though.

Comment: I agree with you, its really dump not to expose capacity, in array queue capacity always stays the same, it should be constant time operation, not like the length which is tricky to get in multithreaded system, and after all you are using array queue not the linked list, capacity never changes.
Maybe they wanted unified API across all queues and not add methods like getCapacity, because it would be tricky to implement constant time operation on all queue classes.

Comment: You're probably right, I suppose it could be omitted to create uniformity between Queues.

Comment: It is only logical solution for me. Maybe there is something else that JDK developer know and we dont

Comment: Why *total* capacity? Is there another kind of capacity? Don't use redundant terminology.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Well yes... that's the trouble. In the case of BlockingQueue there is _only_ `remainingCapacity` and no normal capacity, maybe someone thought it was redundant... But I will edit to save everyone's sensibilities.

Answer (score 3):

For now, I am going with this...

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InformativeBlockingQueue<E> extends ArrayBlockingQueue<E>
{
    private final int visibleCapacity;
    
    public InformativeBlockingQueue(int capacity)
    {
        super(capacity, false);
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public InformativeBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair)
    {
        super(capacity, fair);
        this.visibleCapacity = capacity;
    }
    
    public int getCapacity()
    {
        return visibleCapacity;
    }
}
```

I feel like it should not require an extension just to get the capacity though.